# Разные кодировки в Exception

Tags: исключения, кодировка, php

Есть такой код:

```
try {
    if ($this->stor->exists($name)) {
        return $this->stor->get($name);
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Нет данных для загрузки.');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die($app->name . ' says: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n");
}
```

У меня все файлы цивильно закодированы в utf-8. Соответственно, мой эксепшен выдает нормальную кириллицу, а стандартные исключения почему-то выплевывает в Windows-1251. Как сделать чтобы они тоже были в utf-8?

**UPD:**
Если, допустим сделать так:

```
mb_convert_encoding($e->getMessage(), "UTF-8" , "Windows-1251" );
```

И вырубить БД, выдаст такое:

```
Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]
```

Соответственно, если оставить просто $e->getMessage():

```
����������� �� �����������, �.�. �������� ��������� ������ ������ �� �����������. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]
```

Это точно стандартное исключение и оно точно в Windows-1251.

Comment: Заголовки пробовал ? 

Comment: В смысле - динамически проверять кодировку эксепшена и отдавать в ней? Нет, спасибо, должен быть нормальный способ =)

Answer (score 1):

А какие именно исключения из числа стандартных могут отдавать сообщение в кириллице? Вроде все стандартные для php на английском.

Посмотрите код класса вашего объекта stor. Вероятно файл с этим классом в Windows-1251.